# How to block some robots and referer pages in Apache root level

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, rewrite, wget

When I was using Lighttpd I can easily achieve this by such entries. So all websites were protected.

Wget robots:

```
$HTTP["useragent"] =~ "Wget" {
        $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/tagi(.*)" {
#       $HTTP["url"] =~ "" {
                url.access-deny = ( "" )
        }

        $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/tags(.*)" {
                url.access-deny = ( "" )
        }

        $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/kom.php(.*)" {
                url.access-deny = ( "" )
        }

        $HTTP["querystring"] =~ "^(.*)strony(.*)" {
                url.access-deny = ( "" )
        }

        $HTTP["querystring"] =~ "^(.*)page(.*)" {
                url.access-deny = ( "" )
        }

        $HTTP["url"] =~ "^(.*)/www/delivery/lg.php(.*)" {
                url.access-deny = ( "" )
        }

        $HTTP["url"] =~ "^(.*)/reklamy/(.*)" {
                url.access-deny = ( "" )
        }

        $HTTP["url"] =~ "^(.*)/ads/(.*)" {
                url.access-deny = ( "" )
        }

        $HTTP["url"] =~ "^(.*)/www/delivery/ck.php(.*)" {
                url.access-deny = ( "" )
        }
  }
```

Sites with fake traffic:

```
$HTTP["referer"] =~ "(.*)surfing.php(.*)" {
        url.access-deny = ( "" )
}

$HTTP["referer"] =~ "(.*)promote.php(.*)" {
        url.access-deny = ( "" )
}

$HTTP["referer"] =~ "(.*)trafficadder.php(.*)" {
        url.access-deny = ( "" )
}

$HTTP["referer"] =~ "(.*)traffic.php(.*)" {
        url.access-deny = ( "" )
}

$HTTP["referer"] =~ ".*loic*." {
       url.access-deny = ( "" )
}

$HTTP["referer"] =~ ".*autosurf*." {
       url.access-deny = ( "" )
}
```

How to do this the same in Apache ? I don't want to add this to .htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mod_rewrite which requires a bit of effort. Here are some starting points:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/access.html

Notice in particular the section called "Blocking of robots":
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/access.html#blocking-of-robots

See also:
http://en.linuxreviews.org/HOWTO_stop_automated_spam-bots_using_.htaccess